# how to do linux TCP port forwarding to another server

Tags: linux, nat

how to transparently forward

```
203.131.xxx.xxx:8443 
to 
173.236.xxx.xxx:443
```

can ignore the certification error, just need to change the port number, and let web page content to be display in browser

we CANNOT manage the low level of 173.236.xxx.xxx

- shall we use iptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use iptables:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW  -d 203.131.xxx.xxx --dport 8443 -j DNAT --to-destination 173.236.xxx.xxx :443`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at a packet level with iptables or at the application level with a load balancer like
[HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)